# Compilation fails with non-explicit error message

Tags: sensors, compile

I have written the following code for a project comprising an ultrasonic
distance sensor, a buzzer and a few buttons. When the distance is less
than 60 cm, the buzzer rings and stops only when the appropriate
passcode is pressed.

When I try to compile it, I get:

> exit status 1
>   Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This does not give the **reason** for the compilation failure.

My code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```c++
#include<NewPing.h>  


int r;  
boolean ctr;

#define TRIGGER_PIN  10  // Arduino pin tied to trigger pin on the ultrasonic sensor.  
#define ECHO_PIN     9  // Arduino pin tied to echo pin on the ultrasonic sensor.  
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200 // Maximum distance we want to ping for (in centimeters). Maximum sensor distance is rated at 400-500cm.  

NewPing sonar(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); // NewPing setup of pins and maximum distance.  


//the buttons:  

const int SPEAKER=8;  

const int b1=4;  
const int b2=5;  
const int b3=6;  
const int b4=7;  
//variables to store previous button press and currend button press , used to eliminate switch bouncing  
boolean pb1=LOW;  
boolean cb1=LOW;  

boolean pb2=LOW;  
boolean cb2=LOW;  

boolean pb3=LOW;  
boolean cb3=LOW;  

boolean pb4=LOW;  
boolean cb4=LOW;  


//variables to store numbers:  

int w=0;  
int x=0;  
int y=0;  
int z=0;  



void setup() {  
  // put your setup code here, to run once:  
  pinMode(b1,INPUT);  
  pinMode(b2,INPUT);  
  pinMode(b3,INPUT);  
  pinMode(b4,INPUT);  

 Serial.begin(9600);   



}

boolean debounce1(boolean last1)  
{  
   boolean current1=digitalRead(b1);  
  if(last1 != current1)  
  {  
       delay(5);  
    }  
      current1=digitalRead(b1);  
      return current1;    
  }  

boolean debounce2(boolean last2)  
{  
   boolean current2=digitalRead(b2);  
  if(last2 != current2)  
  {  
      delay(5);  
    }  
      current2=digitalRead(b2);  
      return current2;    
  }  

  boolean debounce3(boolean last3)  
{  
    boolean current3=digitalRead(b3);  
  if(last3 != current3)  
  {  
      delay(5);  
    }  
      current3=digitalRead(b3);  
      return current3;    
  }  

  boolean debounce4(boolean last4)  
{  
   boolean current4=digitalRead(b4);  
  if(last4 != current4)  
  {  
      delay(5);  
    }  
      current4=digitalRead(b4);  
      return current4;    
  }  

boolean distance(int o)  
{  
  boolean control;  
  if (o<60)  
    control=true;  
    return control;  
  }  



void loop() {  
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:  
  cb1=debounce1(pb1);  
  cb2=debounce2(pb2);  
  cb3=debounce3(pb3);  
  cb4=debounce4(pb4);  

     if (pb1==LOW&&cb1==HIGH)     
   {  
      w++;  
    }  
    pb1=cb1;  


    if (pb2==LOW&&cb2==HIGH)     
   {  
      x++;  
    }  
    pb2=cb2;  


    if (pb3==LOW&&cb3==HIGH)     
   {
      y++;  
    }  
    pb3=cb3;  

    if (pb4==LOW&&cb4==HIGH)     
   {  
      z++;  
    }  
    pb4=cb4;  

    delay(50);  
    unsigned int uS = sonar.ping(); // Send ping, get ping time in microseconds   (uS).  

    Serial.print(uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM);  
    Serial.print(" ");  
     int r=uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM;  

     ctr=distance(r);  

  if(ctr==true)  
    tone(SPEAKER,1000);  

Serial.print(w);  
Serial.print(x);  
Serial.print(y);  
Serial.print(z);  


Serial.println();  

delay(100);  
if(w==1&&x==3&&y==3&&z==1)  
  noTone(SPEAKER);  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason. There is always a reason. You may just have to scroll back in the output panel to see it.

```
Tone.cpp:536: multiple definition of `__vector_7'
NewPing/NewPing.cpp:284: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

In this case it is that you are using `NewPing.h` and `tone()`.  Both of them use the same timer.

You can't use both `tone()` and the `NewPing.h` library together without first making one of them use a different timer or no timer at all.  The easiest is the `NewPing.h` library. As it says in the header file:

```
#define TIMER_ENABLED true      // Set to "false" to disable the timer ISR (if getting "__vector_7" compile errors set this to false). Default=true
```

So edit that header file and set `true` to `false` for that line and it should start working.